# How to solve this non-linear system using nleqslv package in R

Tags: r, nonlinear-functions

I´m trying to solve this system with package nleqsl, but I´m not succeeding. Can someone help me?

```
require(nleqslv)

fun<-function(x, E1, V1, E2,V2) {
  y <- rep(NA, length(x))

  y[1]=E1-(x[1]/x[2]+x[4]*x[1]/x[2]^3)
  y[2]=V1-(x[3]/x[2]^2+x[4]*x[1]^2/x[2]^4)
  y[3]=E2-(x[2]/x[1]+x[3]*x[2]/x[1]^3)
  y[4]=V2-(x[4]/x[1]^2+x[3]*x[2]^2/x[1]^4)

  return(y)
}

E1=2.08
V1=0.2
E2=0.505
V2=0.0125
xstart <- c(1, .9, 1,.9)

nleqslv(xstart, fun, E1=E1,V1=V1,E2=E2,V2=V2)
```

Expected answer: x=c(10,5,1,1)

Answer:

```
$x
[1] 13384651 12046186 26769295 24092367
$fvec
[1]  0.96888871  0.19999961 -0.39500014  0.01249974
$termcd
[1] 5
$message
[1] "Jacobian is too ill-conditioned (1/condition=4.7e-018) (see allowSingular option)"
$scalex
[1] 1 1 1 1
$nfcnt
[1] 1
$njcnt
[1] 1
$iter
[1] 2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are values for `E1p`, `V1p`,`E2p` and `V2p`? Are they what you show for `E1` etc? You should also show the complete output of `nleqslv`. It appears the the jacobian is singular. I just tried that and the jacobian is unusable consisting of all zeros.  Please check your function and the inputs.

Comment: Thanks for your attention @Bhas. I know you are the creator of the package. Is there something that I can do to solve this system?

Comment: Your system of equations has not a unique solution. The set of solutions is: `x[2] = x[1]/2`,  `x[3] == x[1]^2/100`, `x[4] == x[1]^2/100`

Comment: Thank you @MarcoSandri. How did you get it?

Comment: Pen and paper...

Comment: Thanks Marco. You are good and fast!

Comment: @MarcoSandri, resolving by hand, which method did you use to simplify the system? Thanks!

Comment: I need to know how to get the 1/2,1/100, 1/100.

Comment: Using eq 1 and eq. 3 you can find x2=x1/2. See here https://imgur.com/a/ugnyz

Comment: I was getting nowhere with my substitutions...Thank you for your patience. The Boldrini`s Hospital Biomolecular Lab and I thank you so much!!